# LibTiff.Net Tiff image = Tiff.Open(fileName, "r") always return null

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, libtiff.net

My C# application has to handle TIFF files, but LibTiff.Net always returns null by this code.

```
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;
...
using (Tiff image = Tiff.Open(fileName, "r"))
{
    if (image == null)
    {
        //Always return null.
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the file exist? Do you specify full path or only the filename?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that I use `image.RotateFlip()` to rotate image.
It changed EXIF (Image metadata) to png, so LibTiff returns `null`